# Try-it Yourself Text Editor

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

How would I create an online editor like the [W3School's try it yourself editor?](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/tryit.asp?filename=trycss_content_noquote)

I've already tried using JQuery's [keyup();](http://api.jquery.com/keyup/) function, but I can't seem to get it to work. Here's what I have so far:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-migrate-1.1.1.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
$("#idinput").keyup( function() {
$("#idoutput").html($("#idinput").val());
} );
</script>
</head>
<body>


<textarea id="idinput"></textarea>
<br>
<div id="idoutput"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Please let me know if I made some simple mistake. I'm very new to JQuery, and this is about the most complicated thing I've written in it so far.

I realize that this might have been asked before, but none of the other solutions have worked. 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Try wrapping it in `$(document).ready(function() { ... })`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your script executes before the `textarea` and `div` even exist.
Try wrapping your code with the following, to delay execution until the document is ready.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  // Your code here.
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
   $("#idinput").keyup( function() {
   $("#idoutput").html($("#idinput").val());
} );
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

The browsers fetches the HTML files from top to bottom. You wrote your JavaScript code before the HTML-elements `<textarea>` and `<div>`.

JavaScript code is interpreted and executed directly when it is loaded (except when it sits inside a function). So the JavaScript already runs while your page is still loading and therefore it won't find your HTML elements.

You should wrap your existing code into `$(document).ready(function(){ ... })` (with JQuery) or into `window.onload = function(){ ... }` (what the JQuery function does in a neater way). The code inside these functions is executed when the page is entirely loaded, so your elements will be loaded and usable.